# File Helper: Write an array to file?

Tags: php, codeigniter

It seems I can't write an array with file helper.

```
write_file('./save/' . $fileName . '.php', $array, 'w+')
```

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fwrite() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
>
> Filename: helpers/file_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 96

Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 4):

Different ways to do that. As the error message is telling you, you'll need a string to store the data. You can use [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to store the value. When you want to use it again as an array, you can use [unserialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

```
write_file('./save/' . $fileName . '.php', serialize($array), 'w+')
```

**Edit:**

Since it apparently does not work well in CI, according to @flux, the code needs to be divided:

```
$serialized = serialize($array);
write_file('./save/' . $fileName . '.php', $serialized, 'w+')
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of implode you could do something like this

```
write_file('./save/' . $fileName . '.php', print_r($array,true), 'w+');
```

where print_r with second parameter -> true will return the printed array as string and save it in your file.
However, with this function, unlike serialize, you won't be able to reuse the array again.